# for loop to recursion JAVA

Tags: java, recursion

I need to write a recursion function that discover a password in a given length, the allowed chars are a-z. I'm not allowed to use loop but i cant get that to work.

here my solution with one for loop that i need to take off some how.

```
public static String findPassword(String p, int length) {
    String pass = "";
    return findPassword(p, length, pass);
}

private static String findPassword(String p, int length, String pass) {

    String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxryz";

    if (pass.length() == length) {
        if (p.equals(pass))
            return pass;
        return "";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < abc.length(); i++) {

        if (p.equals(findPassword(p, length, pass + abc.charAt(i))))
            return findPassword(p, length, pass + abc.charAt(i));
    }

    return "";
}
```

i have tried ever thing I could think of and nothing works.

Comment: _"...that discover a password in a given length..."_ What do you mean by that? What is the ```p``` parameter?

Comment: I don't what you are trying to do, what do you call finding a password ?

Comment: It seems like ```p``` is a string that you're trying to reproduce (since you return when you found an equal string). But then you could just return ```p``` or ```new String(p)```. I don't understand the point of the program.

Comment: I think "pass" is a variable used like in a kind of tail recursion

Comment: p is the password. i need to find her and to only way im allowed to use p is on equals.

Comment: Can you solve this? it is pretty much the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398621/backtracking-bruteforce-java-password-cracker#new-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(findPassword("stack", 5));
}

private static final String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

public static String findPassword(String solution, int length)
{
    return findPassword(solution, length, "", 0);
}

private static String findPassword(String solution, int length, String pass, int alphabetIndex)
{
    if (pass.length() == length)
    {
        if (solution.equals(pass))
            return pass;
        return "";
    }

    if (alphabetIndex < alphabet.length())
    {
        String found = findPassword(solution, length, pass + alphabet.charAt(alphabetIndex), 0);

        if (found.length() == 0)
        {
            return findPassword(solution, length, pass, alphabetIndex + 1);
        }

        return found;
    }

    return "";
}
```

** Your abc String has redundant "r" left to the char "y".

Comment: @IdoSamselik - You are welcome. Appreciate if you could vote me up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting the password in a number and then use recursione to increase the value of p till the value of the converted password:

```
public class Password {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(findPassword(0, "this is the password to find"));
    }

    public static String findPassword(int p, final String passwordToFind) {
        System.out.println(p); //just checkin it's working
        if (p == passToInt(passwordToFind))
            return passwordToFind;
        else
            return findPassword(++p, passwordToFind);
    }

    private static int passToInt(String passwordToFind) {

        int a = 0;
        for (byte b : passwordToFind.getBytes()) {
            a += b;
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

This is not the most beautiful code in the world, and I didn't go deep to see if it's really working, it's just to give you an idea of how to solve it without using a loop, but just a simple recursion.