# Brute-Force java recursive password crack

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, brute-force

I've been given another home assignment that I'm cracking my head about for a week now:
I've been given a class that creates a password of a-z only at a given length.

```
public class Password {
private String _password = "";

// Constructor that generates a password
public Password(int length) {
    Random generator = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        this._password = this._password + (char) (generator.nextInt(26) + 97);
    }
}

//Method that compares a given string to the password
public boolean isPassword(String st) {
    return st.equals(this._password);
}
}
```

Rules:

- If you want to use String class, only the following are allowed: charAt,equals,length,substring.
- You must use recursion.
- You cannot use 26 recursive calls.
- No support methods.
- No arrays.
- No static variables.
- Overloading is ok.

here's what I got until now:

```
public static String findPassword(Password p, int length) {
    String pswd= "";
    char char2Check = 'a';

    if (length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        return findPassword(p,length, pswd, char2Check);
    }
}

public static String findPassword(Password p,int length, String pswd, char char2Check) {
    if (pswd.length() < length) {
            pswd+= char2Check;
            pswd = findPassword(p,length,pswd,char2Check);
        if (pswd.length() < length) {
            if (pswd.length() == 0) {
                if (char2Check == 'z') {
                    return pswd;
                }
                if (char2Check < 'z') {
                    char2Check++;
                    pswd += char2Check;
                    return findPassword(p, length, pswd, char2Check);
                }
            }
            else {
                if (char2Check == 'z') {
                    return pswd.substring(0, pswd.length() - 1);
                }
                if (char2Check < 'z') {
                    pswd = pswd.substring(0, pswd.length() - 1);
                    char2Check++;
                    pswd += char2Check;
                    return findPassword(p, length, pswd, char2Check);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (pswd.length() == length) {
        System.out.println(pswd);
        if (p.isPassword(pswd)) {
            return pswd;
        }
        if (char2Check < 'z') {
            pswd = pswd.substring(0, pswd.length() - 1);
            char2Check++;
            pswd+= char2Check;
            return findPassword(p,length,pswd,char2Check);
        }
        if (char2Check == 'z'){
            return pswd.substring(0, pswd.length() - 1);
        }
    }
    return pswd;
}
```

the problem is:

If the first char is i.e 'r' it will not check a, b or c after it, it'll go stright to s, t, u...

there are a few more problems, but once this problem is gone I think the rest will be easier to solve..

here a paste of the output:
http://pastebin.com/CK9AyKUi

hopefully someone can help me out :)

Comment: You forgot to mention that you must not use any kind of loops like the one over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398621/backtracking-bruteforce-java-password-cracker

Comment: yeah I saw Triple S's question, but couldn't find anything useful there cuz no one posted a code

Comment: *"You cannot use 26 recursive calls"* .... weird ... OK ... simply check for the amount of iterations and add another, empty iteration if you're exactly at 26, if necessary ... that should solve that problem - it doesnt mention *"more"* or *"less"* iterations :)

Comment: they meant like don't write findPassword 26 times, anyway I solved it today, no idea how it works, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all many thanks!

u'r code gave me some good ideas
fixed it for you:)

i have corrected ur code and its works perfect

and here it is:

```
  public static String findPassword(Password p,int length)
  {
      // string and char to be input into the overloading method
      String pswd= "";
      char char2Check = 'a';

      // Checking if the length of the password is 0 so its null
      if (length == 0)
      {
          return "";
      }
      else{
          // going to the overloading method to find the password
          return findPassword(p,length, pswd, char2Check);
      }
  }

  public static String findPassword(Password p,int length, String pswd, char      char2Check)
  {

    // Checking if the length of the password finder is less then the length of the 
    // password we add more chars until they are the same length to check if they're equal
    if (pswd.length() < length)
    {
        pswd+= char2Check;
        pswd = findPassword(p,length,pswd,char2Check);
        char2Check = pswd.charAt(pswd.length() - 1);
        if (pswd.length() < length)
        {
            if (pswd.length() == 0)
            {
                if (char2Check == 'z')
                {
                    return pswd;
                }
                if (char2Check < 'z')
                {
                    char2Check++;
                    pswd += char2Check;
                    return findPassword(p, length, pswd, char2Check);
                }
            }else{
                if (char2Check == 'z')
                {
                    return pswd.substring(0, pswd.length() - 1);
                }
                if (char2Check < 'z')
                {
                    char2Check = pswd.charAt(pswd.length() - 1);
                    pswd = pswd.substring(0, pswd.length() - 1);
                    char2Check++;
                    pswd += char2Check;
                    return findPassword(p, length, pswd, 'a');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Checking if the password finder length is the same as the original password
    if (pswd.length() == length)
    {
        System.out.println(pswd);
        // Checking if the two password match, if so we return the password finder.
        if (p.isPassword(pswd))
        {
            return pswd;
        }
        // Checking if the char is not the last char -> z
        if (char2Check < 'z')
        {
            pswd = pswd.substring(0, pswd.length() - 1);
            char2Check++;
            pswd+= char2Check;
            return findPassword(p,length,pswd,char2Check);
        }
        if (char2Check == 'z')
        {
            return pswd.substring(0, pswd.length() - 1);
        }
    }
    return pswd;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already fixed mine and handed it over, but it'll be good for the next semester or two.

Answer (score 4):

You went to great length for something supposed to be simple: generating all strings of length n containing only a-z characters.

A note about the performances: use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` when you want to do lots of `append` and deletion of chars. String are immutable, so they are copied again and again in your code.

Now, about recursion, you have only two things to think of: what is your general case ? What is your stop condition ?

Here, the stop condition is simple: the real password and current trial have the same length. If the trial is correct, then return it ; else go up in the recursion. Second stop condition: all possibilities have been tried for the current prefix and there is no match, then go up in the recursion.

General case is also simple: given the current prefix, try to append every possible letter a-z and add one level of recursion.

Now, you may want to give it another shot with those leads (hint: fresh start is easier than trying to fix your current code). My solution follows, but you can come up with your own:

```
public static String findPassword(Password p, int length) {
    return findPassword(p,length, new StringBuilder());
}

public static String findPassword(Password password, int length, StringBuilder str) {
    // Stop condition, password and trial have same length
    if (length == str.length()) {
        if (password.isPassword(str.toString())) {
            return str.toString();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    String s;

    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
        // Add a new character to the given prefix
        str.append(c);
        // Try to find a password for the new prefix
        s = findPassword(password, length, str);
        if (!s.equals("")) {
            return s;
        }
        // Didn't work out, remove the character
        str.deleteCharAt(str.length()-1);
    }
    // All chars have been tried without success, go up one level
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I did forget to mention I couldn't use loops of any sort.
I'm trying to work around with what you posted, but it keeps ending after "abcde" rather than keep going till z :(

Answer (score 2):

I won't give you the solution. But assuming the alphabet is "abc" and you want to find passwords of length 3, you would have to program this:

```
a -> aa -> aaa 
|     |      | 
|     |    aab 
|     |      | 
|     |    aac 
|     |        
|    ab -> aba 
|     |      | 
|     |    abb 
|     |      | 
|     |    abc 
|     |        
|    ac -> aca 
|            | 
|          acb 
|            | 
|          acc 
|              
b -> ba -> baa 
|     |      | 
|     |    bab 
|     |      | 
|     |    bac 
|     |        
|    bb -> bba 
|     |      | 
|     |    bbb 
|     |      | 
|     |    bbc 
|     |        
|    bc -> bca 
|            | 
|          bcb 
|            | 
|          bcc 
|              
c -> ca -> caa 
      |      | 
      |    cab 
      |      | 
      |    cac 
      |        
     cb -> cba 
      |      | 
      |    cbb 
      |      | 
      |    cbc 
      |        
     cc -> cca 
             | 
           ccb 
             | 
           ccc
```

There are 2 paths each recursive step you have to check.

- `->`, in case the password is not long enough, try it with `'a'` appended.
- `|`, which increments the last character as long it's not the last of the alphabet.

Both these 2 paths have a stop condition you have to take care for: password length & alphabet length.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static boolean findPassword(Password p, String pswd, int length) {

    if (length == pswd.length()) {
        if (p.isPassword(pswd))
            System.out.println(pswd);
        return p.isPassword(pswd);

    }

    String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length(); i++) {
        if (findPassword(p, pswd + alpha.charAt(i), length)) 
            return true;
    }
    return p.isPassword(pswd);
}
```